# How to save user preferences in Core Data?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data, nsuserdefaults

I am using Core Data to save my data. I preloaded the data from a .csv file. I have an entity named places, with an attribute `isFavorite`. I am populating the data in `UITableViewController`. TableViewCell consists of some labels and a button. When the user taps the `button` the value of `isFavorite` changes from false to true and vice-versa. I want to show the list of favorite places of the user in a separate `tableView`. Only those places are shown in favorite tab whose `isFavorite` value is true.

The problem I am facing is, when the value of `isFavorite` changes on the click of the button say from false to true and the user closes the app. Upon relaunch the `isFavorite` value changes back to the one that is saved in the .csv file.
How can I save the user changes? So that the favorite places remain in the favorite list.

I read a few articles about `NSUserDefaults` but couldn't understand properly. If anyone can help me considering my app's scenario, would be appreciated.

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` has nothing to do with Core Data -- it's more like a dictionary that gets written to a file.

Answer (score 0):

CoreData is there to be persistent, to save the data throughout app launches. If you're preloading your CoreData model with a csv file everytime when the app starts, of course it won't be persisted, as you only loaded the data from the csv file without saving it back. You either have to

- Save your data back to the csv file after every time (hard)
- Save all of your data in CoreData (easier)
- Make a combination between the two (hardest)

Comment: how can i preload my data into coredata without parsing the csv file ?

Comment: @sunnyk You have to parse the csv to get the data out of it, that's how it works. You don't need to do it manually though, I'm sure you can find a parser online

Comment: wouldn't the parser do the same job that i am doing manually. What is the difference ? I m really confused

Comment: What are you doing manually? I don't think you're parsing the csv manually.

Comment: i am using this link to parse the csv file http://www.appcoda.com/core-data-preload-sqlite-database/

Comment: You need to parse the csv file only the first time the App is launched. After that CoreData should manage all the data. After the parsing and import of the csv you can forget the csv and concentrate on CoreData. Read CoreData tutorials, they can explain everything you need after the initial launch

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot to **save**. Each time the user changes the object:

```
// Swift 2.0
do { try context.save() } catch {}
```

Feel free to build out the catch block to do proper error handling.

Comment: this is the problem i am facing now [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326523/how-to-update-existing-object-in-core-data-swift)

Answer (score -1):

You have to save the changes in coreData...it not only has data preload...you can persist data.

The question...how?

i supposed you have in your AppDelegate header this attributes:

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

And in your AppDelegate .m something like it, among other things:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel { .... }

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator { .... }

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext { .... }

- (void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
```

> CoreData class, Places : MTManagedObject

So in your tableViewController where get the action of button when it change between isFavourite ON and isFavourite OFF you have to do:

```
AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = appdelegate.managedObjectContext;

Places *currentPlace = .... get 'place' object to modified from coredata using context object ....
currentPlace.isFavourite = @(isPlaceFavourite); // state get from button

[appdelegate saveContext];
```

> **Note** put your .csv data file into coreData and use coreData not .csv file to load data.

Comment: what do you mean by "put csv file into coreData" ? How can i do that ?

Comment: CSV file or other type of file with your previous data if you are using CoreData it has not sense...so you have to read all data from .csv (only first time) and put it into objects of core data model and save it.


You have to persist your data reading from .csv and creating objects of core data and save your context. After you can delete .csv file and continue using only your core data model.

Comment: I call my preLoad function only if data is not preLoaded. I am not calling the function everytime the app launches.

Comment: Ok! But you have to save context of your current model. If not, core data will continue empty.

Comment: Sorry, i m new to swift. How to save the context ?

Comment: Ok! I put the code in objectiveC. You have to save context using object of kind of 'NSManagedObjectContext' call method 'save' i left you a similar code in objectiveC up.

Comment: Get context in swift from your tableViewController:
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
**let context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88445/discussion-between-sunny-k-and-miguel-angel).